# iOS Store Reviews Discrepancies between itunes and web reviews

Tags: ios

I have an app that i've launched and the reviews that are being displayed in the itunes store are different than those i'm seeing in the web version of the itunes store. Any one have any clue why they'd be drawing off two different databases of reviews?

Thanks

Shan

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app reviews and not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different Appstores for different countries. The reviews in one appstore (e.g., the US appstore) do not appear in the appstores for other countries. Check your web URL and see if it matches the country associated with the Apple ID you are using to check from your iOS device. You can change the web URL easily by typing in the appropriate country code. You can change the appstore you see on your iOS device by logging in to a different Apple ID associated with the other country.

For example, the US appstore URLs will start https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/name-of-app, whereas China appstore will be https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/name-of-app and so on